I'm Facing an Issue while integrating firebase with my flutter app, so i need some help in that case
I'm facing issue while integrating  firebase with my flutter app. I'm entirely new to flutter and watched several youtube videos on this issue but hav'nt found any solution and i've tried to follow every single step explainned in the youtube videos or instructed by the firebase i'm mentioning my "app/build.gradle" code and "android/build.gradle" code here for the sake of getting helped by all the seniors over here,
app/build.gradle code:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.classico"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.classico"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}

android/build.gradle Code:
plugins{
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

and i've pasted a file in the android/app/src named google-services.json.
But i'm still getting these errors, idk how to solve these errors or what i'm doing wrong.
Errors:
"Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: C:/Users/Administrator/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0b7d9e2f04d0deb06f03473cb471b358/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.6.2-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 71748 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
There was a failure while executing work items
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Flutter Projects\classico\android\build.gradle:      │
│ ext.kotlin_version = ''                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
"

Use flutterfire cli for integrating firebase with flutter next time. The problem states that you are using older version of Kotlin. Update your Android studio and Kotlin version. After that run flutter clean to clear cache, after that run flutter pub get to get Dependencies. Now build the apk.

To update Gradle just go to C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Flutter Projects\classico\android\build.gradle and replace what ever is ext.kotlin_version = "HERE" with the latest version number from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

https://console.firebase.google.com check here


select platform Flutter icon

The easiest way to get started is to use the FlutterFire CLI.


add step by step
Refer this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter
simple and easy way to add firebase in flutter

